# Moving in 3D space I want to anchor at some point which give best viewing advantage

Tags: optimization, geometry, computational-geometry, projection

I want to comeup with a point in the image its represented by (a) and (b) such that if I take a picture standing at that point the it presents better grouping of the items (balls)(better viewing advantage - green) . In reality the balls will be not properly organized and scattered around. Is there a way to tackle this mathematically?

So if i am travelling from direction (black arrow) I need to stop at some points (a), (b), etc.. depending upon scatter of the balls such that at single point, the balls capture can be maximized. If can stand at (a) for example in the picture I can take pictures in two directions so this is optimum point encompassing the balls on its left and a single ball on its right.

Assuming the cone has some angle, How shall I mathematically tackle this optimization problem?

---

I am looking for hints. The way I would tackle this is maximization problem by projecting verticle lines from each points/balls , centering my cone and moving as far such that maximum balls at one side can be captured, but the problem is there are balls/points in opposite side as well which might not align well.

[image]